Azure Active Directory app for unified manifest by microsoft
As Microsoft is rolling out Unified manifest for Teams app and outlook add-in. Will there be a single Azure AD app required for both or both Teams app & outlook add-in can have their separate azure AD apps ??
Basically my requirement is to ask permissions from the admin at the time of deployment of unified manifest through office admin center. To achieve this, I have introduced webApplicationInfo property in unified manifest to make sure that the only admin should be able to grant permissions instead of tenant's users.
Since i have separate azure apps for both teams and outlook add-in, i dont want to merge the two Azure apps for my unified manifest.
Can anyone help this ??
Tried using webApplicationInfo in unified manifest to make sure that only admin should be able to grant permission

I'm trying to get help internally in Microsoft to be sure, but I think you're going to have to combine them into a single web application.

@RickKirkham That's what we don't want. If we combine them into one Azure application, then we have to change Azure AD IDs across both teams and outlook and this will inturn ask permissions from users that has already granted permissions earlier and this will not be a good experience for users. Microsoft should provide ways to maintain multiple azure AD across single unified manifest as this will be an universal problem for all orgs who is trying to migrate to unified manifesf
